# cron jobs not working after giving specific time

Tags: cron, cron-task

I want to run a cron job for specific time intervals but when I am trying to specify the time and it is working fine with every minute: `* * * * *`

But it is not working with: 
`0 12 * * *`

Comment: Please update your question to show the *exact*  line that's not working.

Comment: is your server time set correctly?
if it's only matters of 0 12 * * *, it should run okay and it should then be something else.
why don't try to put the whole line in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you intend the cron job to run at midday or at midnight? Note that the range of values for the hour is 0-23, so you should use the 24 hour format:

12 pm: 
`0 12 * * *`

12 am: 
`0 0 * * *`

Comment: i am trying to run at midday its not working if i try to schedule it but its working for * * * * * that is every min its working

Comment: You can try to log into a file, using something like `echo "success: $(date)" >> /tmp/myfile.log` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you reread the documentation on the syntax for `cronjobs` since your expression is not valid. You can use third parties to create `crojobs` for you by passing in parameters. Try the ones below:

- [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)
- [CronJob Generator](http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/)
- [CronTab Generator](http://crontab-generator.org/)